# Prove that $a+b+2\sqrt{ab+c^2}$ cannot be a prime number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

Prove that the number
$$a+b+2\sqrt{ab+c^2}$$
cannot be a prime number for any positive integer numbers $a,b,c$. 
My attempt: 
Suppose that $p=a+b+2\sqrt{ab+c^2}$ is a prime. WLOG assume that $a \geq b$. From the equality we have
$$\left(a+b\right)^2+p^2-2p\left(a+b\right)=4ab+4c^2 \Leftrightarrow \left(a-b-2c\right)\left(a-b+2c\right)=p\left(2a+2b-p\right)$$
Since $0<a-b+2c<a+b+2c<p$, we must have $p |\left(a-b-2c\right)$.  But then I don't know how to continue the way. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: I thought $a=3,b=4,c=2$ was a counterexample, but the last term is $2 \cdot \sqrt{ab+c^2}$ ...

Comment: Then we obtain $p=3+4+2\sqrt{3.4+2^2}=15$ is not a prime number

Comment: I wrote down $a + b + \sqrt{ab + c^2}$ from the title. That's what I meant to say, sorry.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry.  I'll fix it.

Comment: Nitpick.  "Cannot be a prime for *all* $a,b,c$" means that it is not true for *all* $a,b,c$.  That's obvious as it isnt true for $a=1;b=1; c=1$ or for $a=2; b= 8;c=3$.  So it's certainly be true *every* $a,b,c$.  I'm sure you meant it's not true for *any* $a,b,c$.

Comment: Yes, I mean for any $a,b,c$. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your work has almost finished the problem.  $p|(a-b-2c)$ is the key property.

If $a-b-2c>0$, then $a-b-2c\ge p$.  Hence $a\ge b+2c+p$, a contradiction since $a<p$.

If $a-b-2c<0$, then $a-b-2c\le -p$.  Hence $a+p\le b+2c$, so $2a+b+2\sqrt{ab+c^2}\le b+2c$, so $a+\sqrt{ab+c^2}\le c$, again a contradiction.

Finally, if $a-b-2c=0$, then $a=b+2c$.  But then $p=(b+2c)+b+2\sqrt{ab+c^2}$ is even.

Comment: Thank you very much. I forgot $a-b-2c \leq -p$.